# Handling Infinite Scroll Effect Jquery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Why is the url I created getting 404 instead of loading the page data set to each group I want to show on scroll?

I implemented a infinite scroll effect to paginate my data from a table in my mysql database. Now that I am trying to load the page I am getting a 404 error for the url my query is creating.

```
example.com/inventory-search.php?limit=15&offset=0&_=1455489762864 404 (Not Found)
```

I am operating under the impression that the url being formed was specifying the amount of pages and my logic should be keeping track on which page set to be shown. Loading more on scroll.

I did use a tutorial online to get this part of the logic done so I am wondering if I am assuming something that is wrong.

My code looks like this,
DB Config

```
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "username";
$db_pass = "password";
$db_name = "dbName";

try
{
     $DB_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}",$db_user,$db_pass);
     $DB_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $exception)
{
     echo $exception->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Inventory search script,

```
  <?php
require_once get_stylesheet_directory() . '/wuno-search/Dbconfig.php';

$limit = (intval($_GET['limit']) != 0 ) ? $_GET['limit'] : 15;
$offset = (intval($_GET['offset']) != 0 ) ? $_GET['offset'] : 0;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM wuno_inventory WHERE 1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset";
try {
  $stmt = $DB_con->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  echo $ex->getMessage();
}
if (count($results) > 0) {
  foreach ($results as $res) {
    echo '<tr class="invent">';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_product'] . '</td>';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_alternates'] . '</td>';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_description'] . '</td>';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_onhand'] . '</td>';  
    echo '<td>' . $res['wuno_condition'] . '</td>';  
    echo '</tr>';   
  }
}
?>
```

My Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var busy = false;
var limit = 15;
var offset = 0;
var assetPath = "<?php echo $assetPath; ?>"

function displayRecords(lim, off) {
  jQuery.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          async: false,
          url: assetPath,
          data: "limit=" + lim + "&offset=" + off,
          cache: false,
          beforeSend: function() {
            $("#loader_message").html("").hide();
            $('#loader_image').show();
          },
          success: function(html) {
            $("#productResults").append(html);
            $('#loader_image').hide();
            if (html == "") {
             $("#loader_message").html('<button data-atr="nodata" class="btn btn-default" type="button">No more records.</button>').show()
            } else {
             $("#loader_message").html('<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Loading please wait...</button>').show();
            }
            window.busy = false;

          }
        });
}

(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
if (busy == false) {
  busy = true;
  // start to load the first set of data
  displayRecords(limit, offset);
}
});
})( jQuery );



(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
          // make sure u give the container id of the data to be loaded in.
          if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#productResults").height() && !busy) {
            busy = true;
            offset = limit + offset;

            displayRecords(limit, offset);

          }
});
});
})( jQuery );
});
</script>

define $assetPath
$assetPath = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/wuno-search/inventory-search.php';
```

?>

Comment: BTW, you are missing a semicolon after `var limit = 15` and the `assetPath` variable declaration

Comment: Thanks man i fixed it. weird im surprised that did not break my program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of things that could be factors, but what may be the biggest issue is that you are trying to access result properties that you have not `SELECT`ed. For example, you are trying to get `$res['wuno_product']` when you have only selected `id` in your query. You can always do a `print_r($results)` or `var_dump($results)`, etc. to see what the query is returning.

Comment: ahh thanks man, I should of noticed that. So essentially changing that to * should get me everything but when I var_dump i get null

Comment: Open the network tab in your inspector and see what the response says for your request, let me know.

Comment: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
jquery.js?ver=1.11.3:5 GET http://www.example.com/home/site/public_html/monstroid/wp-content/themes/monstroid/wuno-search/inventory-search.php?limit=15&offset=0&_=1455492085677 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Your URL is doing filesystem path instead of server path. Where is `$assetPath` defined?

Comment: I am building this into a wordpress template I created. I added the definition to the  bottom of my question. But so you know what this is,  get_stylesheet_directory() . it's a wordpress function which gets the root template path.

Comment: You probably want `get_template_directory_uri()` or similar instead. Essentially you cannot use the filesystem path for URI.

Comment: But that works to include my files... its just not working to create the link for my paginated pages.